Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4
Кто может помочь начинающему?
Пытаюсь собрать старый проект PatternLockView https://github.com/aritraroy/PatternLockView и получаю ошибку:
"Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4."
в build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.4.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

ext {
    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 25
    compileSdkVersion = 25
    buildToolsVersion = '25.0.2'

    // dependencies
    supportV7 = 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    rxJava = 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.2'
    rxAndroid = 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.0'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Поскольку JCentr закрылся, добавил mavenCentral()
  buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

Все равно пишет:
Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.4/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.4.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.4/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.4.pom

Как решить данную проблему?
P.S. Вроде бы нашел gradle-bintray-plugin на https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jfrog.bintray.gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.4

Но вставка maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact' } также не помогает
Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.4.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.4/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.4.pom
       - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.4/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.4.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.4/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.4.pom

Есть еще скачанный откуда то, возможно с github, gradle-bintray-plugin-1.4.zip (похоже в виде проекта), но пока не знаю как его, если это возможно, подключать локально.

Может кому то поможет, необходимо добавить следующий репозитарий:
maven { url 'https://releases.jfrog.io/artifactory/oss-releases/' }

Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
